# Приложение не запускатеься на IIS после добавления loggerFactory.Add

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

Не могу понять в чем проблема, в дебаге и релиз версии все запускаеться нормально, как только я публикую приложение на IIS то при обращении к приложению 500 ошибка 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если закомментровать строку  `loggerFactory.AddStorage( LogDataBase );` то все нормально.

```
public void Configure(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

    var LogDataBase = new DataBase();
    string connectionString = configuration[ "AppSetting:Log:ConnectionString" ];
    string procedureName = configuration[ "AppSetting:Log:ProcedureName" ];
    LogDataBase.InitializeSqlServerConnection( connectionString, procedureName );

    loggerFactory.AddStorage( LogDataBase ); // <----
```

Подскажите где можно посмотреть в каком месте возникает ошибка когда приложение уже крутится на IIS?

Comment: IIS на локальной машине? Доступ с сайта есть к БД? Текст ошибки можете привести?

Comment: Да на локальной машине. Причем я создавал пустое приложение и переносил туда кусок кода логгирования и там проблема в том же месте(это для чистоты эксперимента что бы снять подозрения с других сервисов). Без publish'инга все работает отлично, но когда я публикую на сервер то при запуске ошибка 500, а что внутри происходит не понятно и где это посмотреть не ясно. Да к БД есть подключение. А где посмотреть текст ошибки, если приложение запущено на локальном IIS? Можно ли там запустить отладку?

Comment: Авторизация в БД какая? Windows или логин\пароль зашитый в строке соединения? Я не знаю как в asp.net core разрешить показ деталей ошибки в IIS - это вам надо отдельным вопросом спросить или погуглить

Comment: Там локально стоит MS SQL Expressа соединяюсь я сним вот так "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LocalDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" может тут проблема?

Comment: Запустите пул приложения от своей учетки и проверьте

Comment: Да вы правы проблема оказалась где то в участке где происходит работа с БД, я заклментировал весь код внутри методов класа DataBase и приложение перестало падать. Но вот почему оно падает? Видимо надо создать какую то отдельную учетную запись в БД для этого приложения и что бы оно ходило в БД по этой учетке. Не знаю как это делать сейчас буду гуглить. Спасибо что не оставили в беде.

Comment: Все проблема решена: я включил sa на сервере и разрешил использовать учетные записи SQL Server